# CSS Float behaviour (even after checking W3C)

Tags: html, css, css-float, w3c

I have an issue with float and have included the sample code below. I am trying to create a two column layout: I know how to do this a number of other ways so this question is with a view to finding out why FLOAT behaves the way it does here.

- The container DIV has two DIVs, both are floated left.
- As expected, the size of the browser window determines whether or not the second floated block level element will go alongside or under the first floated element.
- The problem arises with the length of the content in the second floated DIV (assume the browser window is maximized, at whatever resolution).

In the code below, I have commented out part of the second paragraph. On my browser this is the cut off mark: including any content after this causes the whole DIV to clear the first DIV, even though there is a lot of space left in the second DIV before it should need to clear the first DIV.

I cannot see anything in the code that should cause this to happen. I am aware of how float behaves in terms of block level and inline content and the consequences of placing non-floated blocks beside floated ones, but I cannot find anything in the documentation to explain why the block should clear when there seems to be sufficient room for its content.

Help much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>CSS Float Problem</title>

<style>

body {
background:#5c604e;
}

#container {
position:relative;
background:yellow;
}

p {
background-color:#cccccc;
    width:50%;
}

.block {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.float {
 float: left;
}

.pink {
 background: #ee3e64;
}

.blue {
 background: #44accf;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="container">
<div class="block pink float">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer Nam fringilla Vestibulum massa nisl. Nulla adipiscing ut urna ipsum Curabitur urna lacinia pretium feugiat Ut. 
</div>   
<div class="blue float"> <h2>Test Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum erat a neque eleifend vitae ultrices nisi tempor. Praesent facilisis lobortis nisl, <!--sit amet gravida orci mollis vitae. Maecenas porta turpis id urna porta id ornare velit dapibus. <!--    Proin sollicitudin, tortor viverra posuere mattis, nisl est rhoncus urna, nec elementum augue turpis vitae diam. Pellentesque ut quam sit amet elit tempus suscipit nec vel nulla. Proin ullamcorper sollicitudin metus in posuere. Aliquam a vehicula odio. Morbi scelerisque arcu ac nibh cursus ullamcorper. Aliquam pulvinar commodo nunc nec laoreet. -->   
    </p>
</div>
</div><!--end of container div --> 
</body>
</html>
```

See it at http://cssdesk.com/86cPH

Comment: I've dumped it at http://cssdesk.com/86cPH, in future if you can provide such a demo it'd be helpful.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with that. Thanks, I'll do that in future.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have two block-level element floated next to each-other. Because they're block-level, they establish a new containing context in which their contents will live and affect layout.

The standard behaviour when calculating box sizes for floated elements is to base it on the contents of the element. Because your second floated box doesn't have an explicit width, the browser determines that its width should be based on its contents, which in the case of the floated element is going to be as wide as its contents can feasibly be.

Thus, the second box flows underneath the first because the intrinsic width of the paragraph affects the blue box, which is larger than the allotted explicit constraints of its container (i.e., the width of #container minus the width of the first floated element).

---

If you wanted the text to flow around the floated element, you should omit the "blue" box. Only when the float and the contents are nested in the same container (and the content isn't a block-level element) will the content then flow around the pink box as one might expect.

---

As far as getting a working two-column layout with equal-height columns, I'd recommend trying `display: table` if you don't need to support IE7.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That the browser determines the remaning available width based on the width of the containing div minus the width of the first floated element makes sense, but I would have presumed that there is actually more space available. When testing my example there is an obvious visible space for more text. Is the absence of specific widths for both the container div and the second floated div going to mean that I can never predict at what point the browser will clear the first float? Is there somewhere in float's definition that states this, or is it received wisdom from experiment?

Comment: It's a pretty simple model: every element has a box, that box has a calculated width. If the box is floated, it will shrink to the smallest width possible for its content. If its content could feasibly be a single line 1000px long, then that's how long the floated element would be unless there's something to restrict its width from growing that large -- namely, its bounding box (or containing element, if you will). As I said in the response, the only way you'll get content to flow to the side of a float is by having the content + float nested in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve? you haven't fixed the width of second block and so its width is going mad with the content length.

Give it a fixed width.
If you want that rest width is covered by it then try this.

```
.block1 {
    width:20%;
}


.block2 {
    width:80%;
}
```

and in html

```
<div class="block1 pink float"> ..content.. </div><
div class="block2 blue float"> ..whatever content.. </div>
```

remember there should be no space between closing div  of left block and opening div of right block else whitespace between them will cause them to stacked over one another

Comment: That's certainly helpful; I can get it to behave as expected by setting explicit widths for both the container div and the second of the floated divs. I still don't fully understand the feature of the float rule that makes it behave the way it does in my example.